# Disabling RegBack

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

In Windows 7, I find a folder `C:\windows\System32\config\RegBack` wherein registry files are being created during boot-up.

Few queries regarding the same:

1. What are entries in `RegBack` folder used for? I did some search in
   internet and it seems windows does periodic backup of registry files
   in this folder. If this is true, what is the duration in which
   windows takes backup of the registry and is that duration
   configurable?
2. Is it possible to disable the creation of `RegBack` folder and its
   contents? When i checked the entries immediately after bootup, this
   folder has all zero-sized files.

`Directory of C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack`

`12/11/2010  02:13 AM    <DIR>          .`

`12/11/2010  02:13 AM    <DIR>          ..`

`11/22/2014  10:52 AM                 0 SYSTEM`

`11/22/2014  10:52 AM                 0 SOFTWARE`

`11/22/2014  10:52 AM                 0 SECURITY`

`11/22/2014  10:52 AM                 0 DEFAULT`

`11/22/2014  10:52 AM                 0 SAM`

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are used in conjunction with System Restore Points.  Why on earth would you want to disable it?

Comment: I have a requirement wherein either the file should be present before boot up or it has to part of overlay memory of `fbwfmgr`. These files are not part of both which is unacceptable according to my requirements.

Comment: No; Its not possible to disable this feature.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the info. Is it possible to configure the time duration in which the registry backup will be taken? Is it possible to see the current settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the task and time configured for the registry backup from the below steps

1.Go to the Task scheduler,

2.Now transverse to Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows ->Registry.

3.On the right side you can see the task is scheduled every 10 days at 12 a.m so you can change it.